# Automatically open a file on startup on system boot or Window 7 start up (an Image or a Video file in default Video Player)

Tags: windows-7, boot

Is it somehow possible that then my computer starts then an Image should be opened automatically at the startup or a Video file automatically starts to play on a Boot(or Reboot)? Does Window 7 has such feature.

Comment: You can do this a number of ways on startup.  If you provide a bit more detail of your situation, I'm sure someone will guide you towards how to accomplish this.

Comment: Actually, I have written 10 Rules in the form of an image. when I wake up and start my machine I want to read them first to lead a happy day and a happy life. + a Motivational Video → This should be automatic on start up or I will tend to become lazy, and do not open those things in the long run________

Comment: @ Cheesus Crust You there?

Comment: Personal computer?  If so, then I will try and write up a simple script that will open up the image and video for you on startup.  You will need to place it in your `Startup` folder yourself though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script can accomplish this.

You will need to place it in your **Startup** folder for it to run automatically when you turn on your computer.

First we will need to create the script;

1. Open **Notepad** and save the file with `.bat` at the end of the file name.

   - This will turn the file into a **Batch** file or script.
2. Then enter this into the file and save (Replace the placeholders with the locations of the files)

> timeout /t 5
>
> "PATH TO IMAGE HERE"
>
> "PATH TO VIDEO HERE"

3. Leave the quotations, just replace the words inside them with the path.
4. Make sure it is saved to your **Startup** folder.

   - `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Once you have ensured the paths are correct and it is in your **Startup** folder, it should load the image up first and follow up with the video after you close the image.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: can you please guide me what extension should I save for video →https://www.screencast.com/t/RbYk6HQzW8 ; I have done like this for Image →  https://www.screencast.com/t/SwsdlyjLUC

Comment: `troy.mkv` should suffice..Did it not work?

Comment: I am struck → C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Copuld not find AppData folder looks like private.

Comment: Sir, the video got opened, but the image didn't → https://www.screencast.com/t/kia7AKa66IC

Comment: My Bad the extension was wrong for Image. i wish I could give you 10 UPVOTES for such a help. Thanks!